# How to a add a command to a WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command, textblock

I'd like to be able to click a textblock and have it run a Command. Is this possible?
(if not do I just somehow make a tranparent button over it or something?)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use a [InputBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx).

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

Edit: Hyperlink is probably worth a mention too.

```
<TextBlock><Hyperlink Command="" TextDecorations="None" Foreground="Black">Hello</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
```

Comment: This would quite great if it did not fire on mouse down, still +1 though for simplicity...

Comment: Yeah, MouseBinding can be a bit limited at times. The Hyperlink method I added executes on MouseUp

Comment: Awesomesausage!  I just changed it to `LeftDoubleClick` and got exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 25):

You do not make a transparent button over it, you put the TextBlock *into* it:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: You may also add `MinHeight="0"` to button.

Answer (score 0):

Well the button would consume your click and the click would not go further to your `TextBlock`. If you don't need that, that would be one way to do it. You can modify the textblock ControlTemplate, and add the button, giving the button a new ControlTemplate with a transparent RectangleT. A nicer solution would be to use a way to hookup commands to events like [EventBehavior](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html) and put it on the `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` event.