# Using Commands in WPF TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, treeview, command, hierarchicaldatatemplate

is there a way to use commands in a treeview with a HierarchicalDataTemplate, so that i can react on the click on an item in the treeview?
i would prefer a solution without code-behind if there is one.

Here is my TreeView:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Main.TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>                     
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>                
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

provide an property of type ICommand on your Item (ViewModel) and Bind to that. So your item class would be something like:

```
class MyTreeItem
{
   public MyTreeItem()
   {
      this.SomeCommand = /* create command here */ null;
      this.Children = new ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem>();
   }

   public ICommand SomeCommand { get; private set; }

   public ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

In xaml you can then write:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Main.TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>                     
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
            <Button Text="My Command" Command="{TemplateBinding SomeCommand}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>                
</TreeView>
```

I think that should work, at least it did similarily last time i used that :)

Comment: ok on the button i can use the command property. but thats not nice to have buttons in the treeview. ;-) is there a way to do that on the click on the textblock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003507/how-to-a-add-a-command-to-a-wpf-textblock is probably what you are looking for :)

Comment: thats a good solution and it works well if my textblock is not in the treeview. but for my problem it doesn't work if the textblock element is used in the treeview. any idea why?

Comment: are you sure you are using a template binding?

Comment: templatebinding is not available for the mousebinding and i don't want to use the button in a treeview

Comment: you could also restyle the button? from a control perspective what you are doing is changing the appearance of a button.